# Internal Server Error (500) Firebase hosting (Failed to lookup view)

Tags: firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, ejs, firebase-hosting

System:

```
node.js: v18.17.0
npm: v9.8.1
firebase: v12.4.6
OS: Windows 11
```

Github repository: https://github.com/yanivavraham1/cuponim1

Problem Description:

I'm a starting web developer and trying to learn to to use `Firebase functions` using `ejs` and `express.js`. I deployed this project to `Firebase Emulators` and it worked properly I could see the store data displayed on the page (at localhost:5000/stores/KSP). Now after that I deployed it to `Firebase Hosting` but when I reached the route `/stores/KSP` [You can try yourself](https://cuponim-a4dce.web.app/stores/KSP)
I get `Internal Server Error` apper on screen and error(500) in console.

In firebase:functions:log I got that its unable to find the view store.ejs:
`restApi: Error: Failed to lookup view "store" in views directory "/public/views"`

this line made me think the problem could be 1. the cloud function can't access the public folder 2. store.ejs not exist in the project at the hosting. I can't figure out how to fix it (if its true)

functions/index.js:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const express = require('express');
const ejs = require('ejs');
const path = require('path');
admin.initializeApp();
const app = express();

// Serve static assets from the "public" directory
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));

// Set the views directory and view engine
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '../public/views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/cart', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    res.render('cart');
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error retrieving store data' + error });
  }
});

app.get('/stores/:storeId', async (req, res) => {
  const storeId = req.params.storeId;
  try {
    const snapshot = await admin.database().ref('stores/' + storeId).once('value');
    const storeData = snapshot.val();

    if (storeData) {
      const storeName = storeData.NameEnglish;
      res.render('store', { storeData: storeData });
    } else {
      res.status(404).json({ error: storeId + ' not found ' + storeData });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error retrieving store data' + error });
  }
});

exports.restApi = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

I successfully fixed it by moving the views folder into the functions directory but I want the views folder to be in public because I want to use files (in store.ejs) which is in public (can't move them to Functions directory)

Comment: Someone just disliked my post please discribe the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
res.render('store', { storeData: storeData });
```

seeks to render the `store` view, via passing an object (btw, you can simplify `{ storeData: storeData }`, which is a trick you can do in Javascript if the name of the attribute matches the name of the variable to be assigned to it). The view is searched for inside `/public/views`, where the system simply did not find a `store` view to render. This is how you were setting up the path:

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '../public/views'));
```

You will need to make sure that you have the view you want to render, it's at the location where you expect it to be, the user executing this code has the necessary privilege to access the view and the path given here is correct.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. If I understand correctly you say that I should make sure that store.ejs exist in public/views ? I can tell  that in my local project (also in the github repository) it does exist. How can I make sure its been uploaded to Firebase?

Comment: I just noticed that the my github repository was private, I just changed it

Comment: @YanivAvraham yes, you understand my answer correctly. I can confirm that I can see the template in your repository. But I do not know much of your Firebase configuration. I would look at the machine where the template is being searched for whether it is indeed there. If so, maybe there is a privilege problem. It happens quite often that the OS user who runs the script is different from the user who owns your template and the former cannot see the file, even though it exists at the correct place.